# Enabling ssl through existing certificate in solr

Tags: java, ssl, solr, jetty-9

I need to load the existing .crt file in solr, jetty-9 web server to enable ssl using keytool/openssl commands. Anyone help me to solve this out ?

when i try to use the existing certifacate, i can see this in console,

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8443 [-]  
Started Solr server on port 8443 (pid=61455). Happy searching!
```

but in browser,

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Self-signed certificate is working well (reference : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL)

Comment: Hi, Are you seeing the same error message in all the browser? What version of Solr you are using? Are you trying to access using IP/ HOST NAME?  Can you post the below property values in your solr.in.sh/ solr.in.cmd  
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=